# Video Played Counter in PHP

Tags: php, video, counter

I have a flash player embeded in my PHP page. It plays video recordings. I want to restrict a particular user to play a specific video upto 3 times. Please suggest, how can i know that an user has viewed a particular recording or not. Can I track the time of played recording.

Comment: which flash video player ? or is it your own written player ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can achive this ( have a db table to store the user id, video id, count times, and last played date, then for example if you whant to let the user view the video 3 times in a week just have a cron run each day and remove the entryes that have last played date > than 7 days ) .

1. count when the page loads, but this raises a problem if the user doesn't play wthe video ...

OR

1. send an ajax request from the player a few seconds before the song ends, this asumes you make another ajax request from the player at the start of the video to check how many times the user has played it .